# Implement two way syncing with Mysql In Iphone

Tags: iphone, csv, core-data, synchronization, offline

In my App I Want to implement two way syncing with My server. I want to work offline When I do not have internet. I have managed core data for that. But at starting of my app I want to load all my data(that contain text , images) to sqlite file.

Is it a good approach? I think It is not user friendly. After Offline work I need I want to sync the changed data with server. I achieved it with the CSV File(text in CSV file and all  my images are going with NSURLSessionDataTask). But this work is so complex to handle. Can any one help me with a good solution. Every solution is welcome